# How to manually set x-axis range in ListPlot

Tags: plotting

If I were to plot `ListPlot[{{5, 7}, {-2, 2}}]`, then mathematica automatically sets the x-axis range which is from -2 to 5 in this case. I want to set this manually, such as from -5 to 5, regardless of the x range of the list (I can do this for y-axis by adding `PlotRange->{-5,5}`). How do I do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange!

You almost had it yourself - `PlotRange` is the key here.

```
ListPlot[{{5, 7}, {-2, 2}}, PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, Automatic}]
```

[image]

This behaviour is described under the details in the [`PlotRange`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange.html) documentation, specifically:

[image]

We are using the form that is second-from-the-bottom, but setting `Automatic` for the `y` axis.

Comment: If I use this, it changes the range of y axis. I want to manually set both x and y ranges.

Comment: @user62606 That is unclear from the wording of your question. `PlotRange->{{-5,5}, {-5, 5}}` will do what you're looking for, and if you look at the documentation for `PlotRange` as I linked in the answer, there are lots of examples of how to do more with it.